# Manually map 1 to Many Relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to map an existing database in EF with code first. The provider (jetEntityFrameworkProvider) does not support DB first.

I am trying to map the Table "Component" (1) to the Table "ComponentText" (Many)

This is what I have

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(p => new { p.ComponentText });

            m.ToTable("ComponentText");


        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentText>().HasKey(t => t.ComponentCounter);
    }
```

When I run it I get the follow error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'ComponentText' on type 'Component' cannot be mapped because it has been explicitly excluded from the model or it is of a type not supported by the DbModelBuilderVersion being used.'

These are my models with only the relevant properties

Component

```
[Table("Component")]
public class Component
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Counter")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("Name")]

    public virtual ICollection<ComponentText> ComponentText { get; set; }

}
```

ComponentText

```
[Table("ComponentText")]
public class ComponentText
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Counter")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TextId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    //** Foreign Key
    public int ComponentCounter { get; set; }
}
```

ETA:

I've changed my code per Backs answer. However, it is still not working. I have tried several variations. .HasRequired(), .HasOptional().

Note I removed m.ToTable("ComponentText"); As Component is already mapped in the class to  the "Component" Table.

I am getting 0 results and receiving this error in Results View

> Error = The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

If I uncomment the section line in the comment `modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentText>().HasKey(t => t.ComponentCounter);`

I get this error

> Component_ComponentText_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Component_ComponentText_Target' in relationship 'Component_ComponentText'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    private DbConnection con = new JetConnection();

    public ProjectContext() : base(new JetConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = 'C:\Users\Ben-Laptop\Desktop\Test-Project.sep'; User Id = Admin; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = SEEME;"), true)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ProjectContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Component> Components { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().HasMany(p => p.ComponentText).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(p => p.ComponentCounter);

        //modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentText>().HasKey(t => t.ComponentCounter);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `m.Properties(p => new { p.ComponentText });` because it only maps property `ComponentText`
2. Add mapping for collection

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().Map(m =>
       {
           m.ToTable("ComponentText");
       })
       .HasMany(p => p.ComponentText)
       .WithRequired()
       .HasForeignKey(p => p.ComponentCounter);
   }
   ```

[Entity Framework Fluent API - Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Backs: That got me further but I am still having issues. please see my edit.

Comment: @TheColonel26 you don't need `modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentText>().HasKey(t => t.ComponentCounter);`. Yourprimary  key is `Id`

Comment: OK well, that explains that. However, when I comment that out I am still getting 0 results on Components. Whereas before, I was getting 223.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed that issue. I'll mark it as answered.